# combining probibilities

Tags: probability

I am working my way through Probability and Statistics for Computer Scientists 2nd ed.  And am stuck on how to answer the following question:

2.10 Three computer viruses arrived as an e-mail attachment. Virus A damages the system with probability 0.4. Independently of it, virus B damages the system with probability 0.5.  Independently of A and B, virus C damages the system with probability 0.2. 
What is the probability that the system gets damaged?

Since the events are not mutually exclusive I can not just add them but so to answer this don't I need more information?  i.e. Some values for the intersection of A,B & C so that the combination of these events adds up to less than 1?

P.S. I am not in any kind of course, and this is not an assignment.  I am doing it for my own interest.

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Since the events are not mutually exclusive I can not just add them but so to answer this don't I need more information? i.e. Some values for the intersection of A,B & C"

For independent events $U$ and $V$ you have $P(U \cap V) = P(U)P(V)$

The probability that the system gets damaged is

$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cup B \cup C) & = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)  \\ 
 & - P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap C)-P(B \cap C) \\ 
 & + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
 &  \\ 
 & =0.4+0.5+0.2-0.4 \cdot 0.5-0.4 \cdot 0.2-0.5 \cdot  0.2+0.4 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.2=0.76
\end{align}
$$

---

Here we are subtracting the double intersections.

Maybe you are familiar with the formula

$P(U \cup V) = P(U) + P(V) - P(U \cap V)$

It is the same principle. Draw a Venn diagram if you need to convince yourself.

Finally we are adding $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ because we have subtracted too much.

---

This comes from the principle of inclusion-exclusion

and is used for calculating the union of non-disjoint events.

Comment: Thanks that is the piece I was looking for.  Now all I have to do is remember it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find first the probability the system *does not* get damaged. This is the probability that Virus A causes no damage **and** Virus B causes no damage **and** Virus C causes no damage.

*Remark*: You could find the intersection probabilities you refer to by using independence, but that is more work.